# Floated divs inside centered div, how do i do?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a centered div on a website, in which I need to float two divs. The left one is of constant width but the right one changes width and needs to be a constant distance from the right side of the centered parent div.

non-working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/aZx4e/

### EDIT

I have tried all your examples but the contained items still floats to the left/right of the site, way outside of the parent div :(

Comment: Can you post a sketch of what you'd like the working example to look like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `<div>` doesn't have a `width` attribute =)

Comment: `margin-right:20%;` (change 20 for your constant number) is what you need?

Comment: @rudie it says non-working example ;) didn't really try it out since i knew it wasn't going to work

Answer (score 2):

How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/aZx4e/3/

Comment: the parent div has to be centered aswell.

Comment: The yellow div is centered.. What else do you need centered? See http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/aZx4e/3/embedded/result/ for bigger viewport. This is what I see (Chrome 11): http://screencast.com/t/9e9UCoVLdB - Is that not exactly what you want?

Comment: then something is really screwed up with my code :( i guess i'll just have to rework it completely...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:250px; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: solid 2px;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        constant width
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; padding-right:20px;">
        dynamic width
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Added the padding-right style.  Change the 100px to what you want your constant distance from the right edge of the parent div to be.  I also added an empty div w/clear:both.  This is important when floating to ensure other parts of your document aren't accidentally floated, which can occur in IE.  You should get in the habit of adding a clear div as the last sibling of any elements you float.

Comment: Edited width on the parent div after noticing @Rudie's comment.

Comment: I think i would need code to center the parent div aswell since that's where it starts to screw up

Comment: I had assumed that your div was already centered.  I've done this; but I don't have the work on me.  I'll post back later with how I centered the div.

Comment: @Filip, I've included how to center the div as well.  The border is just to show you where the div is.  You can remove it once you're confident it is centered.

Comment: I updated the widths to be a little smaller.  You should note that if the parent div isn't wide enough to contain both child divs, then it is going to render funny.  So either set the width to auto, or make sure it is wider than the sum of the widths of both of your child divs (and don't forget to take your padding into account).  I used this method on a site I'm building, and it should work on all major browsers.